# converting a string into array of pointers to characters

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to write a code to convert a string into an array of pointers, each pointer points to a word in that string. when I compile the code below and print every word separately inside the first loop I get every word alright, but after the loop finishes and then I try to print each word in the array through a loop , all elements of the array are the same which is the last word in the string.

If we passed "ab cd ef" to this function, the last loop will print

```
ef then ef then ef
```

but if I print every element of the array in the first loop it will print

```
ab then cd then ef
```

Code

```
void sort(char* str)
{
    char* a[100]={NULL};
    char *tStr2,*min,*temp;
    tStr2=(char*)malloc(strlen(str));
    int i=0,i2=0,j=0;
    while(i<=strlen(str))
    {
        if(str[i]!=' ' && i!=strlen(str))
        {
            tStr2[i2]=str[i];     //copy every word separately to tStr2[]
            i2++;
        }
        else
        {
            tStr2[i2]=NULL;
            a[j]=tStr2;           //word is complete --> copy it to the array
            printf("%s \n",a[j]); //print every word
            j++;
            i2=0;                 //initializes the word counter
        }
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    for (i=0;a[i];i++)            //loop is complete , print all array elements
        printf("%s \n",*a[i]);
}
```

Comment: `std::string` and `std::vector` and `std::stringstream` are your friends here.

Comment: This is C or C++?

Comment: 1) C is not C++ is not C. 2) Pick one of them 3) Format the code. It is unreadable.

Comment: This code is C, through and through. As a C++ developer, I take offence to calling this C++ due to declaring vars at the start of the scope and the use of printf, strlen and malloc. :)

Comment: @lfgtm: Same for me if I get another Areduino question tagged C. You're welcome to edit the tags if you dare!

Comment: Well `tStr2=(char*)malloc(strlen(str));` is a C++ construct so it looks like the user is using some sort of C++ compiler.

Comment: @NathanOliver . Good spot. However this can still be successfully compiled with gcc (rather than g++) due to a GNU extension which allows non ANSI standards (thanks GNU!... not). If OP is using gcc try compiling with '-pedantic' flag. ;) It won't compile anymore.

Comment: There's no question here at all. You should read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - the first step being to actually ask a question. You've described the problem, but not given a clear indication as to what exactly you need help with.

Comment: I am asking why the printf() at the end prints the last element of array three times instead of printing every element one time

Comment: I am using a GNU GCC compiler in code blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a[j]=tStr2;` copies the same pointer to the various elments of `a[]`.  So later on when code prints `a[j]`, it refers to the text.

Code needs to save different pointers in the various `a[j]` elements.  Perhaps as simple as the common, but non-standard, `strdup()`.

```
a[j] = strdup(tStr2);
```

Additional code needed to `free()` this allocation.

An alternate approach would copy `str` once and replace its `' '` with `'\0'` and have `a[j]` point to the various beginning "words".

Comment: but why the first printf() prints correctly but the second one doesn't ?

Comment: @Ahmed M. Salah With your code `a[j]=tStr2;` each prints from the _same_ buffer: `tStr2`.  The first loop `printf()` is called, `a[0]` points to `tStr2` and `tStr2[]` has `"ab"` in it.  The next time first loop `printf()` is called, `a[1]` points to `tStr2` and`tStr2[]` has `"cd"` in it.  The last time first loop `printf()` is called, `a[2]` points to `tStr2` and `tStr2[]` has `"ef"` in it.  When the 2nd `printf()`s are called, `a[0], a[1], a[2]` all point to the same buffer: `tStr2`.  That buffer contains `"ef"`.

Comment: wow thanks mate you are the man, that explained this behavior, and strdup() worked !!!!, any further advice to improve this piece of code

Comment: so the best method to copy string from a character pointer to another is strdup() right ?

Comment: @Ahmed M. Salah the best code to "copy string from a character pointer to another" is `strcpy()`.  The best code to allocate memory, create a copy of a string and assign a pointer of that copy is `a[j] = strdup(tStr2);`